# How to put a break point in text in d3.js

Tags: d3.js, label, pie-chart

I am drawing a piechart and i would like to have the labels with a break point. The labels are status and percentage which i get from csv file.

```
var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
        .data(pie(data))
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "arc")


        g.append("path")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .style("fill","#FFFFFF")
        .transition()
        .ease("bounce")
        .duration(2000)
        .delay(function(d, i) {return i * 1000;})
        .style("fill", function(d) {return color(d.data.Source);});

        g.append("text")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .html(function(d) { 
            if (eval(d.data.Components) >0)
               {
                   return ((d.data.status) + " </br>  "  + "     " + d.data.Percentage + "%");
               }

    });
```

Comment: You can use tspan like this: http://jsfiddle.net/2NLJY/1/

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the `tspan` and `text` elements is the `foreignObject`. You can append a `foreignObject`, then append normal HTML. For you it would like something similar to this:

```
g.append("foreignObject")
  .attr("width", "100px")
  .attr("height", "100px")
  .append("xhtml:div")
  .html(function(d) { 
    return ((d.data.status) + " <br>  "  + "     " + d.data.Percentage + "%");
  });
```

I've found this approach easier to work with than `tspan` and `text` elements in the past, as it doesn't involve appending and positioning more elements than necessary.

Comment: hii @jczaplew i tried ur code its working fine for me.  actually in my case when text appended while someone mouse over on node.  and all links info display with newline. but when user move mouse on other node then previous information stick there only. it should replace but its overlapping. can u tell me how to figure out this prb

Answer (score 1):

The `text` element does not allow `br` tags in it.

From the [docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#Introduction):

> Each ‘text’ element causes a single string of text to be rendered. SVG performs no automatic line breaking or word wrapping. To achieve the effect of multiple lines of text, use one of the following methods:
>
> - The author or authoring package needs to pre-compute the line breaks and use multiple ‘text’ elements (one for each line of text).
> - The author or authoring package needs to pre-compute the line breaks and use a single ‘text’ element with one or more ‘tspan’ child
>     elements with appropriate values for attributes ‘x’, ‘y’, ‘dx’ and
>     ‘dy’ to set new start positions for those characters which start new
>     lines. (This approach allows user text selection across multiple lines
>     of text -- see Text selection and clipboard operations.)
> - Express the text to be rendered in another XML namespace such as XHTML [XHTML] embedded inline within a ‘foreignObject’ element. (Note:
>     the exact semantics of this approach are not completely defined at
>     this time.)

In your case, for example, you'll have to put `d.data.status` and `d.data.Percentage + "%"` in two different `tspans` in the `text` element and manually specify `dy` on them to align them vertically, [like the examples shown here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#TSpanElement).